# Extreme low performance when using a high number of integer & binary variables in Pulp

Tags: python, pulp

when modelling a lp production problem, I use a high number of integer.

First the problem was being solved in a reasonable time but when I added a big number of binary values (y) due to big M method, it takes hours and hours and the program doesn't appear to be working at all. This is because Pulp is quite slow with binary variables.

The reason I did big M is because I wanted to seperate the variable bounds, in order to get

x(i,t) = 0 or x(i,t) >= 10 (which means **either produce nothing or at least 10 pieces** of product i in every time period t):

> x(i,t) - 1 <= e + M * y(i,t)
>
> x(i,t) - 9 >= -e - (1 - y(i,t) ) * M

(e is a very small constant number and M a very big constant number)

Is there any other way than using the method shown above?
I could define the bounds of x(i,t) like [10, inf] but I still need the value 0, since producing nothing is also a very valid important solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are formulating like that with big M and the small constant for integer/binary variables.

If `x` is integer and `y` is corresponding binary variable, re-formulate to this:

```
x <= y * M
x >= y * 10
```

Where `M` is a logical upper bound on `x`

This is similar to what you had, but the small constant `e` is unnecessary and M should not be overly huge.

All solvers (including the one pre-packaged in `pulp` slow significantly with the introduction of large numbers of binary or integer variables, under most conditions.

Have you tried setting a mip-gap or such to convince yourself that it is working?

Comment: Because then the bounds would be different/infeasible??  If y=1, then x is smaller than 1 and also larger than 10 simultaneously?

Comment: Yeah, I fat-fingered that....  fixed!

Comment: ah okay, makes sense and the constraint is better readable but the actual problem is that I have to use a new binary variable y which drastically reduces the performance of the algorithm

Comment: I also tried fracGap=0.05 which is now a lot faster, thx! before i tested it only with fracgap=0.01 and had no effect. so I have to trade-off optimality against speed which is accepable for me.
thank you!